# Java, 2nd material interaction not functioning?

Tags: java

```
public class EventsClass implements Listener {

    @EventHandler
    public void onInteract(PlayerInteractEvent event) {
        Action action = event.getAction();
        Player player = event.getPlayer();
        Block block = event.getClickedBlock();

        if (action.equals(Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK)) {

            if (block.getType().equals(Material.EMERALD_BLOCK)) {

                if (player.getHealth() == 20) {
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Your health is full!");
                } else {
                    player.setHealth(player.getHealth() + 2);
                    player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "You've been healed by 1 heart!");
                }

                if (block.getType().equals(Material.REDSTONE_BLOCK)) {

                    if (player.getHealth() == 1) {
                        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "This cannot kill you!");
                    } else {
                        player.setHealth(player.getHealth() - 2);
                        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You've been damaged by 1 heart!");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I've got no idea why the second part (the damage part) is not working, there are no errors, everything checks out. (I am kind of new to this so if I done something very obvious please point it out) This is for a Minecraft plugin, incase you're interested.

Comment: missing `}`before `if(block.getType().equals(Material.REDSTONE_BLOCK)) {` Indentation should help you. 2 similars conditions (here the block type) should probably be on the same indentation level

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. I can't believe I made that mistake. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Hmm, it seems that after doing that the if to stop them for killing them self has stopped working, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the main question: the indentation fo your code should leads you to the problem:
you have a missing closing bracket before the second block type check.

An easy way to check is to correctly indent your code (as you did). Similar conditions usually stand on the same indentation level.

Now there are thing that won't work as you expect:

- What happens if you use an emerald while you have 19hp? You get to 21hp.
  You probably should add a case to add only 1 hp to the health bar.
- What happens if you use a redstone will having 1 hp? You die. Change the condition to `player.getHealth() <= 2`

Here is what you should get :

```
if(action.equals(Action.RIGHT_CLICK_BLOCK)) {
    if(block.getType().equals(Material.EMERALD_BLOCK)) {
        if(player.getHealth() == 20) {
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Your health is full!");
        } else if(player.getHealth() == 19) {
            player.setHealth(player.getHealth() + 1);
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "You've been healed by half a heart!");
        }else{
            player.setHealth(player.getHealth() +2);
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "You've been healed by 1 heart!");
        }
    } if(block.getType().equals(Material.REDSTONE_BLOCK)) {
        if(player.getHealth() <= 2) {
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "This cannot kill you!");
        }else {
            player.setHealth(player.getHealth() -2);
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "You've been damaged by 1 heart!");
        }
    }
}
```